# select statement with max function

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select, max

I am trying to write a statement which will show me clients who did not  pickup more than 2 months
i already have update procedure for it and it works as it must be

```
update Clients
set StatusID=4
from (SELECT P.ClientID, MAX(p.PickupDate) MaxPickupDate
      FROM Pickup P
      group by P.Clientid) P
     join Clients C on P.ClientID= C.ClientID
where   C.StatusID in (1, 2)and C.WIC=0
      AND P.MaxPickupDate<DATEADD(month,-2,GETDATE());
```

I have other select

```
select P.ClientID
   ,LastName+' '+FirstName as Name 
   ,Address
   ,max(p.PickupDate)
from Pickup P
join Clients C on P.ClientID= C.ClientID
where max(p.PickupDate)<DATEADD(month,-2,GETDATE())
group by p.clientid, lastname + ' ' + firstname,address
```

it supposed to show me only clients who did not do pickup for more that 2 months 
but it throwing me error

> An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a
>   subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column
>   being aggregated is an outer reference.

looks like it doesn't like this line  `where max(p.PickupDate)<DATEADD(month,-2,GETDATE())`Any Ideas how to fix this problem?

Comment: Use `HAVING` instead of `WHERE`. http://stackoverflow.com/q/287474/139010 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/6319183/139010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use HAVING instead of WHERE since the logic needs to be applied after the aggregation is done and not before:

```
select P.ClientID
   ,LastName+' '+FirstName as Name 
   ,Address
   ,max(p.PickupDate)
from Pickup P
join Clients C on P.ClientID= C.ClientID
group by p.clientid, lastname + ' ' + firstname,address
HAVING max(p.PickupDate)<DATEADD(month,-2,GETDATE())
```

Comment: i was trying this approach but it throwing me error `Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'group'.`