# Using an aggregate function in where

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, aggregate-functions

I saw a few threads here with similar questions however I couldn't find something fitting my needs.

Consider the following table and example data:

```
CREATE TABLE foo(a int, b int);

INSERT INTO FOO VALUES(1, 3);
INSERT INTO FOO VALUES(1, 3);
INSERT INTO FOO VALUES(1, 4);
INSERT INTO FOO VALUES(2, 5);
INSERT INTO FOO VALUES(2, 3);
INSERT INTO FOO VALUES(3, 10);
```

Consider this query:

```
SELECT a,
       sum(b)
FROM foo
GROUP BY a;
```

It works fine. I want to alter that query so that it will only match groups where the sum is bigger than 9. My (failed) attempt is:

```
SELECT a,
       SUM(b)
FROM foo
WHERE SUM(b) >9
GROUP BY a;
```

What is the correct way to do it in postgres ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Aggregate function in SQL WHERE-Clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319183/aggregate-function-in-sql-where-clause)

Comment: In case you wondered, I downvoted this question. To prove this question is asked a lot, I pasted the exact title of the question in Google. The first two results were exact duplicates of this question on StackOverflow. Therefor, I think this question, though coherent and nicely formatted, doesn't show much research effort.

Comment: A fair point. Downvote accepted.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't use aggregate expression in the `where` clause - this is what the `having` clause is for:

```
SELECT   a, SUM(b)
FROM     foo
GROUP BY a
HAVING   SUM(b) > 9
```

Answer (score 1):

try it with the "having" clause!

```
SELECT a,
   SUM(b) FROM foo
GROUP BY a having sum(b) > 9;
```