# Retrieve rows with unique values in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, algorithm

I am stuck at with this query. Any help would be appreciated

Write a SELECT statement that returns the name and discount percent of each product that has a unique discount percent. In other words, don’t include products that have the same discount percent as another product.

Comment: sounds interesting, hope you pass the exercise without anybody getting greedy reputation

Comment: pls vote down lazy students

Comment: A suggestion: do not post a complete solution, just the key to it.

Comment: Post what you've tried so far so we can see what your level of understanding is.  If you cannot, you need more study.

Comment: the guy did not even try... the other day one gy even had the illustrations fro the problem posted online, before starting the planing he was asking here. No way, man, just a google search and the problem is solved, this one went to bed and will check back tomorrow for a complete solution

Answer (score 1):

1. With `GROUP BY`, `COUNT()` and `WHERE`, identify the unique discounts. Note that [`WHERE` cannot be used with an aggregation function as-is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319183/aggregate-function-in-sql-where-clause);
2. `SELECT` the rows using the retrieved set .