# Using MIN in where clause

Tags: sql, t-sql, min

Trying to change the following code to allow me to use min in where clause

```
SELECT od.personID
,'Uno' AS [CustomerType]
FROM dbo.orderDetails od
WHERE od.orderDate BETWEEN CONVERT(date, '2016-02-01') AND @StartDate
AND MIN(odd.orderDate) BETWEEN CONVERT(date, '2016-02-01') AND @StartDate)
GROUP BY personID
```

Comment: cheers, that is so silly of me. Its been a long day forgetting basics lol

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Aggregate function in SQL WHERE-Clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319183/aggregate-function-in-sql-where-clause)

Answer (score 6):

Move the `MIN`  to the `HAVING` section

```
SELECT od.personID
,'Uno' AS [CustomerType]
FROM dbo.orderDetails od
WHERE od.orderDate BETWEEN CONVERT(date, '2016-02-01') AND @StartDate     
GROUP BY personID
HAVING MIN(odd.orderDate) BETWEEN CONVERT(date, '2016-02-01') AND @StartDate
```

Comment: just a quick question that statement in having clause means that the first order date of that person is between that date period right? just clarifying

Comment: if I add on the statement `COUNT(PersonID) = 1` in the having clause that will restrict the results to only those customers that only bought once?

Comment: Yes, but I will use `AND COUNT(orderDate) = 1`  or `orderID` to make it more readable about what are you counting ;).

Comment: ah yes ofcource. Cheers Thanks.